# Add multiple fees to WooCommerce per product, based on category or tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to add 2 custom product fees on my woocommerce store based on the product category.
Custom fee 1 $3,60 for all products in category 39
Custom fee 2 $1,80 for all products in category 38

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
function df_add_ticket_surcharge( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $specialfeecat = 39;
    $spfee = 0.00;
    $spfeeperprod = 3.60;

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        $proid = $value['product_id'];
        $quantiy = $value['quantity'];
        $itmprice = $value['data']->price;

        $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' );
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $catid = $term->term_id;
                if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
                    $spfee = $quantiy * $spfeeperprod;
                }
            }
        endif;
    }

    if($spfee > 0 ) {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Statiegeld', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'df_add_ticket_surcharge' );
```

This works as expected, all products in product category: 39 get the custom fee in checkout.

The problem I'm having is to get this to work with another product category & value. When I try copying the same code twice it returns a critical wordpress error.

What I'm trying to achieve is= 
Custom fee 1 $3,60 for all products in category 39
Custom fee 2 $1,80 for all products in category 38

If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would use a switch statement to conditionally set the price for each category based on the category id. See below:

```
function df_add_ticket_surcharge( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $spfee = 0.00; // Move the initialization outside of the loop

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        $proid = $value['product_id'];
        $quantiy = $value['quantity'];

        $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' );

        $spcustomfee = 0.00;

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $catid = $term->term_id; // Get the id
                // Set each id to the fee you want to charge/
                switch ( $catid ) {
                    case 39:
                        $spcustomfee = 3.60;
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        $spcustomfee = 1.80;
                        break;
                    // Add more cases for other categories if needed
                }
            }

            $spfee += $quantiy * $spcustomfee;
        }
    }

    if ( $spfee > 0 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Custom Fee', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'df_add_ticket_surcharge' );
```

Comment: Edit: by changing this line of code: 
 $spfee += $quantiy * $spcustomfee; to:
 $spfee = $quantiy * $spcustomfee;
The correct fee shows up, however the issue still persists when products from both categories are added to cart, the fee from product category 38 is not showing up anymore.

Comment: @dosrox - just updated the code. The `$spfee` is moved outside the loop so the fee for each product is properly added to it. It should now work when you add both products to the cart.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking another look. sadly it still doesnt seem to work. When I add both of the products to the cart the fees wont add up,